# Cython: How to use templates?

Tags: python, cython

I would like to cythonize the following templated C++ class:

```
template <typname T>
class Fc2Par
{
public:
  Fc2Par(std::string const& par_file)
  ~Fc2Par()
  std::vector<Box<T>> convert_boxes(std::vector<Box<T>> const& boxes) const;
  std::vector<Point<T>> convert_points(std::vector<Point<T>> const& points) const;
private:
  PartitionMap<T>  par_map;
  PartitionRTree<T> par_idx;
};
```

In reality, T will be [int, double] only. Box/Point are additional templated classes but I'm not sure if i want to expose that in python. To cythonize, I have the following, but I'm stuck in some areas. I think I can use a fused type for T?

```
cimport cython
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string

my_fused_type = cython.fused_type(cython.int, cython.double)

cdef extern from 'Fc2Par.h':
  cdef cppclass Fc2Par[T]
    Fc2Par(string&) except +
    vector[Box[T]] convert_boxes(vector[Box[T]]&)
    vector[Point[T]] convert_points(vector[Point[T]]&)

cdef class PyFc2Par:
  cdef Fc2Par* thisptr <-- should this be Fc2Par[my_fused_type]*?

  def __cinit__(self, par_file):
    self.thisptr = new Fc2Par[my_fused_type](par_file)
  def __dealloc__(self)
    del self.thisptr
  def convert_boxes(self, boxes)

    I'm not sure what to do here?

  def convert_points(self, points)

    This will be very similar to convert_boxes once I figure that out.
```

Ideally, I want to use the API in python like this:

```
boxes_int = [(0,0,1,1), (0,0,2,2), ...]
boxes_float = [(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0), (0.0,0.0,2.0,2.0), ...]

fc2par = PyFc2Par('foo.csv')
converted_int = fc2par.convert_boxes(boxes_int)
converted_float = fc2par.convert_boxes(boxes_float)
```

They return a list of tuples with xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax.

**My Questions:**

1. Is using a fused type correct in this situation?
2. If I take a list of tuples, how do I convert them into Box[T]/Point[T] in the Cython code without exposing these classes in Python? Once I have the result, I can convert that back to a list of tuples and send that back. i.e., how should the convert_boxes implementation look like?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 - unfortunately you can't use fused types there. (See previous questions on the subject: [c++ class in fused type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400469/c-class-in-fused-type); [Cython: templates in python class wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436593/cython-templates-in-python-class-wrappers)). You have to create a separate wrapper for each different variant. e.g.:

```
cdef class PyFc2ParInt:
  cdef Fc2Par[int]* thisptr
  # etc ...

cdef class PyFc2ParDouble:
  cdef Fc2Par[double]* thisptr
  # etc ...
```

This unfortunately involves a lot of unavoidable code duplication.

Question 2. The implementation if `convert_points` essentially involves iterating through a Python list creating your boxes and then iterating through the vector to create a Python list. A rough outline is:

```
def convert_points(self, points):
   cdef vector[Box[double]] v # or vector[Box[int]]
   for p in points:
      # I've taken a guess at what the Box constructor looks like
      v.push_back(Box[double](p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3]))

   v = self.thisptr.convert_points(v) # reuse v for the output

   # now iterate through the vector and copy out
   # I've taken a guess at the interface of Box
   output = [ (v[i].left, v[i].right, v[i].top, v[i].bottom)
              for i in range(v.size()) ]
   return output
```

Note that you need to have told Cython about `Box` (`cdef extern from ...`), even if you don't then expose it to Python.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I was able to get it working using the approach you described.